# Qt: Why only one style from qss file work

Tags: python, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I am using qss file in my project. The whole code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Win(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setStyleSheet(
                           'QWidget{background: rgb(150, 150, 150);};'
                           'QPushButton{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 100px;};'
                           'QLineEdit{background-color: yellow; font-size:5px;};'
                           )

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        lay1 = QVBoxLayout()
        btn1 = QPushButton('btn')
        lay1.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addLayout(lay1, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        lay2 = QVBoxLayout()
        label1 = QLabel('label')
        lay2.addWidget(label1)
        layout.addLayout(lay2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        lay3 = QVBoxLayout()
        edit = QLineEdit('edit')
        lay3.addWidget(edit)
        layout.addLayout(lay3, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setRowStretch(1, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Win()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am using ```setStyleSheet` to control my window, and the result is:

[image]

We can find that only `QWidget{background: rgb(150, 150, 150);}` work. I want the background color of `QPushButton` to be red by `'QPushButton{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 100px;};'`, and the background color of `QPushButton` actually is not red.

Then, if I comment the `'QWidget{background: rgb(150, 150, 150);};'`, and the new code is:

```
        ...
        self.setStyleSheet(
                           # 'QWidget{background: rgb(150, 150, 150);};'
                           'QPushButton{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 100px;};'
                           'QLineEdit{background-color: yellow; font-size:5px;};'
                           )
        ...
```

Now, the result is:

[image]

We can find that `'QPushButton{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 100px;};'` works, but `'QLineEdit{background-color: yellow; font-size:5px;};'` still do not work.

How can I make the three styles work?

```
'QWidget{background: rgb(150, 150, 150);};'
'QPushButton{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 100px;};'
'QLineEdit{background-color: yellow; font-size:5px;};'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in the QSS syntax since after `}` there should not be a `;`:

```py
self.setStyleSheet(
    "QWidget{background: rgb(150, 150, 150);}"
    "QPushButton{background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-size: 100px;}"
    "QLineEdit{background-color: yellow; font-size:5px;}"
)
```

Furthermore, many styles behave differently with QSS, for example I have obtained a correct result with the fusion style:

```py
app.setStyle("fusion")
```

[image]